# How to associate a DHCP pool or subnet with declarations for a class

Tags: pxe-boot, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have the following working configuration for ISC DHCP server 4.1.1, which hands out fixed addresses to registered clients.  Some of those clients are configured for PXE booting (for [FAI](http://fai-project.org) and [SCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager)).

```
# General declarations
authoritative;
option domain-name            "department.example.edu";
option domain-name-servers    8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time            86400;

class "fai" {
    match hardware;
    next-server fai.department.example.edu;
    filename "fai/pxelinux.0";
}

class "sccm" {
    match hardware;
    next-server sccm.department.example.edu;
    filename "sccm/pxelinux.0";
}

# Public network (one of many).
# Ethernet outlets are in public areas.  By policy we require users to
# register their MAC addresses, and clients obtain fixed addresses.
subnet 10.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
    option subnet-mask        255.255.0.0;
    option broadcast-address  10.20.255.255;
    option routers            10.20.0.1;
}

# Three of many hosts registered for fixed address assignments in the public network
host host1.department.example.edu {
    hardware ethernet ca:fe:ba:be:00:01; fixed-address 10.20.1.1;
}

host linux2.department.example.edu {
    hardware ethernet ca:fe:ba:be:00:02; fixed-address 10.20.1.2;
}
subclass "fai" 1:ca:fe:ba:be:00:02;

host windows3.department.example.edu {
    hardware ethernet ca:fe:ba:be:00:03; fixed-address 10.20.1.3;
}
subclass "sccm" 1:ca:fe:ba:be:00:03;
```

---

Now, I would like to add support for another subnet where we will hand out dynamic addresses from a pool to any DHCP client (because all Ethernet outlets on that VLAN are at the IT workbench in a secure location).  The question is, **what is a good way to make the existing SCCM declarations the default for the IT workbench?**

```
# New IT workbench subnet.  I'd like the "sccm" settings to be the default
# for this subnet.
#
# The VLAN only has outlets in a secure location, so MAC address registration
# is not necessary.
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask        255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address  192.168.1.255;
    option routers            192.168.1.1;
    pool {
        range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;
        # Point A: what declarations to put here, if anything?
    }
    # Point B: what declarations to put here, if anything?
}
# Point C: what declarations to put here, if anything?
```

---

Conceptually, I could write at Point B

```
    next-server sccm.department.example.edu;
    filename "sccm/pxelinux.0";
```

but that would be repeating myself.  I'd like to take associate the subnet with the existing `"sccm"` class, if possible.  What could I write that has the effect of

```
    subclass "sccm" "anything-in-192.168.1.0/24";
```

(I don't *have* to use a class for the SCCM declarations.  If a group or some other mechanism works, that would be fine too.)